# Добавление данных в таблицу из lineEdit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt5

Есть база данных, в базе есть три таблицы Input, Outpu, Product.
Необходимо внести данные в таблицу Input из lineEdit по нажатию кнопки.
Много что смотрел, читал и пробовал. Где-то затык.
Код ниже:

```
/* Подключаем заголовочный файл для работы с информацией, которая помещена в базу данных */
class DataBase;


class InputDataTable : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    InputDataTable(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~InputDataTable();


private slots:
    void closewindow();
    

private:
    Ui::InputDataTable ui;
    QSqlTableModel *model;
    DataBase *db;
    
private:
        void addinfo_clicked();
            
};

*.cpp

InputDataTable::InputDataTable(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)

{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.closepushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &InputDataTable::closewindow);
    connect(ui.addpushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &InputDataTable::addinfo_clicked);
       
}

InputDataTable::~InputDataTable()
{
    
}
void InputDataTable::closewindow()
{
    close();
}


void InputDataTable::addinfo_clicked()
{
        
    QSqlQuery query = QSqlQuery();

    query.prepare("INSERT INTO Input (Name, Money, Date, Comments)"
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    QString str1 = ui.namelineEdit->text();
    QString str2 = ui.moneylineEdit->text();
    QString str3 = ui.datalineEdit->text();
    QString str4 = ui.commentslineEdit->text();
    query.addBindValue(str1);
    query.addBindValue(str2);
    query.addBindValue(str3);
    query.addBindValue(str4);
    query.exec();
    
}
```